# history.go() how to get the index of a specific visited page url from window.history?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a web application that has button if click will go to a specific history. I heard that only IE supports history.go(url) but other browsers accept only numeric value. In my case the history.go() will go to specific page only e.g. `http://localhost:54187/Products/Create`. Even if users navigated to different page if the button is click it still goes to "create" page of the history. I need history.go since it's equivalent to browser back and forward. I cannot use window.location or location.href since my application requires that filled in data are still there exactly what history.go does. If the user loads a total of 26 pages how will I know which of these 26 is the create page so that I can history.go(createIndex)? window.history.length gives 26 but it doesn't expose the url.

Please help how can I resolve my problem.

JavaScript and HTML

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
    $('#btnGoToCreate').click(function () {
        var createIndex = //how to know what's the index of 
        //http://localhost:54187/Products/Create from window.history?
        history.go(createIndex);
        });
    });
   </script>

<input type="button" value="Go to Last Entry" id="btnGoToCreate" />
```

Comment: _“I cannot use window.location or location.href since my application requires that filled in data are still there”_ – that is more a matter of caching than _how_ a page is navigated to. And if you need data that the user input before again, you should save it into your session, so that you can read it from there.

Answer (score 0):

You can't *read* the history items because of security/privacy reasons. You can only access the previous URL, which can be read using the following:

```
document.referrer
```

You can [**manipulate** the browser history](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history) though, but that also doesn't allow you to go to the specific page in the user's history.

Answer (score 0):

Add a counter variable to save the index. This counter could be stored in  `cookie/sessionStorage/localStorage`.
When the user navigates to another page, counter self plus 1, finally you could use window.history.go(counter) when the user clicks the button.

BTW, counter could self plus 1 when user refresh the page, to avoid this issue from happening, you need to pass a timestamp to the next page, use `?timestamp=1231232123`, and save in `cookie/sessionStorage/localStorage`, if the timestamp in the url is different to the one save in `cookie/sessionStorage/localStorage`, then the counter could plus 1.

This is my solution in my project, hope can help you.